# TFS 2010: Automating builds based on Labels?

Tags: tfs

I need to set up an automated CI build that executes in the following order:

1) Label all files in source control with new label.
2) Get only files that have the new label
3) Build + version + Test

I need to be certain that I am only building files that I have labeled.

All ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is interested, TFS 2010 support this out-of-the-box.

Build process:

After the latest version has been taken (Changeset1), TFS "lable" the code in the "workspace". Now, if there had been another check-in (Changeset2) just before this label is applied, TFS will **ONLY** lable the previous changeset (Changeset1). - This I believe the correct behaviour. Changeset2 should go to the next build.

I initially thought TFS labels the second check-in even though the "Workspace" only has changeset1.